# Angular 2 HTTP Post: Cannot get and use response object

Tags: typescript, angular

I am currently working on an Angular 2 project that uses RESTful as the back end.

Here is a short scenarior that can help me ask my question.

When a user Logs in, I want to redirect to a profile/order page that displays some user details.

In order to achieve this, I have a Register.ts
and in here my code looks like this.

```
export class RegisterService{
    public isLoggedIn:boolean;
    public userDetails:any;
    public newUser = new User("","","",null);

    constructor(private _http: Http){
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }


    Register(data:any) {
        const body = JSON.stringify(data);
        // console.log(data);
        this.userDetails = data;
        // console.log("userdets: "+this.userDetails.username);
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this._http.post(`http://192.168.20.17:8080/webshop/api/user/create?username=`+data.username+`&password=`
                                +data.password+`&email=`+data.email+`&city=`+data.city+`&housenumber=`+data.housenumber+
                                `&street=`+data.street, body, {headers: headers}
        );
    }
Login(data:any):Observable<any>{
        const body = JSON.stringify(data);
        // console.log(data);
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this._http.post(`http://192.168.20.17:8080/webshop/api/user/login?username=`
            +data.username+`&password=`+data.password, body,{headers:headers})
            .map((res:Response)=> JSON.stringify(res));
        // console.log(this.newUser);

    }
```

And then in my sign-in.component.ts, I have methods that uses this service as shown below

```
  onLogin(_username:string, _password:string)
    {
        const data = {
            username:_username,
            password:_password,
            }

        this._registerService.Login(data)
            .subscribe(
                data=> resolve(data.json())
            )
        console.log(this.response);}
onPost(username:string, email:string, password:string, housenumber:string, street:string, city:string)
{
    const data = {
        username:username,
        email:email,
        password:password,
        housenumber:housenumber,
        street:street,
        city:city
    }
    if (data == null)
      this.isValid == false;

    else {
        this.isValid == true;
        this._registerService.Register(data).subscribe(
            data=> this.response = JSON.stringify(data),
            error => console.log(error)),
            data=>console.log(data);
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data)
            );

        if(localStorage.getItem("user") != null) {
            this._registerService.isLoggedIn = true;
            this._router.navigate(['/order']);
        }
        else
        //replace this with a page
            alert("Sign in with a correct name!");

    }
}
```

I am able to display the user's details when they signUp but when a user logs in, I cannot get the response which is meant to be a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "address": {
    "addition": null,
    "city": "Nijmegen",
    "housenumber": "908",
    "street": "de Voorstenkamp"
  },
  "email": "ernestina_a@ive.com",
  "password": "678",
  "username": "feedme"
}
```

I tried to create two classes, User.ts

```
import {Address} from "./Address.ts";
export class User {
    username:string;
    email:string;
    password:string;
    address:Address;

    constructor(username:string, email:string, password:string,address:Address){
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public static createEmptyUser():User{
        return new User("","","",null);
    }
}
```

And address.ts

```
export class Address {
    street:string;
    housenumber:string;
    addition:string;
    city:string;


    constructor(street:string, housenumber:string,addition:string,city:string) {
        this.street = street;
        this.housenumber = housenumber;
        this.addition = addition;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public static createEmptyAddress():Address {
        return new Address("","","","");
    }

}
```

Using this two classes, I tried to parse the response to get a user object but I am not able to get any response at all.

Can anyone here help me out ? I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am just showing an example how to get the body part from any http response:

```
getMemberList(){
      this.teamService.getMemberList().subscribe(
        (res)=>{
                  console.log("getMemberList: ",res.json());
        },
        (err)=>{
                  console.log(err);
        }
      )
  }
```

In the above code I have called an HTTP POST request in `teamService.ts` . So after coming response from any API you will have to do `res.json` to get the body part from response.